# How to configure i18n in Spring boot 2 + Webflux + Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-webflux

I just start a new project based on Spring boot 2 + Webflux. On upgrading version of spring boot and replace `spring-boot-starter-web` with `spring-boot-starter-webflux` classes like

- WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

  LocaleResolver

  LocaleChangeInterceptor

are missing. How now can I configure defaultLocale, and interceptor to change the language?

Comment: Check https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-web-handler-api using LocaleContextResolver.

Comment: Could you please provide the content of the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, LocaleResolver, LocaleChangeInterceptor?
Did you extended this class for your purpose?

Comment: @virsha read again my question. I do not have this entities. They are part from mvc dependency i use instead webflux

Comment: Spring webflux has a webflux configurer adapter for webflux config, eg. see [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/mvc-thymeleaf/src/main/java/com/example/demo/WebConfig.java), Similar with `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, you can find all optional configuration provied in `WebFluxConfigurer `.

Comment: Hope this helps [link](https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-internationalization/)

Answer (score 8):

Just add a `WebFilter` that sets the `Accept-Language` header from the value of a query parameter. The following example gets the language from the **language** query parameter on URIs like `http://localhost:8080/examples?language=es`:

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.server.adapter.DefaultServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import static org.springframework.util.StringUtils.isEmpty;

@Component
public class LanguageQueryParameterWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private HttpWebHandlerAdapter httpWebHandlerAdapter;

    public LanguageQueryParameterWebFilter(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void loadHttpHandler() {
        this.httpWebHandlerAdapter = applicationContext.getBean(HttpWebHandlerAdapter.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(final ServerWebExchange exchange, final WebFilterChain chain) {
        final ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
        final MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams = request.getQueryParams();
        final String languageValue = queryParams.getFirst("language");

        final ServerWebExchange localizedExchange = getServerWebExchange(languageValue, exchange);
        return chain.filter(localizedExchange);
    }

    private ServerWebExchange getServerWebExchange(final String languageValue, final ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        return isEmpty(languageValue)
                ? exchange
                : getLocalizedServerWebExchange(languageValue, exchange);
    }

    private ServerWebExchange getLocalizedServerWebExchange(final String languageValue, final ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        final ServerHttpRequest httpRequest = exchange.getRequest()
                .mutate()
                .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.set("Accept-Language", languageValue))
                .build();

        return new DefaultServerWebExchange(httpRequest, exchange.getResponse(),
                httpWebHandlerAdapter.getSessionManager(), httpWebHandlerAdapter.getCodecConfigurer(),
                httpWebHandlerAdapter.getLocaleContextResolver());
    }
}
```

It uses `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)` in order to avoid cyclic dependencies.

Feel free to test it and provide feedback on this POC.

Comment: This answer is so underrated. Thanks for this great implementation!

Comment: It can be implemented much easier, because you can just mutate the exchange instead of creating a `DefaultServerWebExchange`. Then neither `ApplicationContext` nor `HttpWebHandlerAdapter` with the `@EventListener` trick are required.  See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47527504/how-to-configure-i18n-in-spring-boot-2-webflux-thymeleaf/75196938#75196938)

Answer (score 3):

With spring-boot-starter-webflux, there are

- DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration
- LocaleContextResolver

For example, to use a query parameter "lang" to explicitly control the locale:

1. Implement `LocaleContextResolver`, so that 
   `resolveLocaleContext()` returns a `SimpleLocaleContext` determined by a GET parameter of "lang". I name this implementation `QueryParamLocaleContextResolver`. Note that the default `LocaleContextResolver` is an `org.springframework.web.server.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleContextResolver`.
2. Create a `@Configuration` class that extends `DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration`. Override `DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration.localeContextResolver()` to return `QueryParamLocaleContextResolver` that we just created in step 1. Name this configuration class `WebConfig`.
3. In `WebConfig`, override `DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration.configureViewResolvers()` and add the `ThymeleafReactiveViewResolver` bean as a view resolver. We do this because, for some reason, `DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration` will miss `ThymeleafReactiveViewResolver` after step 2.

Also, I have to mention that, to use i18n with the reactive stack, this bean is necessary:

```
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:/messages");
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(5);
        return messageSource;
}
```

After creating a natural template, some properties files, and a controller, you will see that:

- `localhost:8080/test?lang=zh` gives you the Chinese version
- `localhost:8080/test?lang=en` gives you the English version

Just don't forget `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in `<head>`, otherwise you may see some nasty display of Chinese characters.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Spring Boot 2.4.0, the `WebFluxAutoConfiguration` contains a bean definition for the `LocaleContextResolver`, which allows us to inject custom `LocaleContextResolver`. For reference, the following is the default bean definition in Spring Boot 2.5.4 (the implementation may be different in earlier versions):

```java
@Bean
@Override
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = WebHttpHandlerBuilder.LOCALE_CONTEXT_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME)
public LocaleContextResolver localeContextResolver() {
    if (this.webProperties.getLocaleResolver() == WebProperties.LocaleResolver.FIXED) {
        return new FixedLocaleContextResolver(this.webProperties.getLocale());
    }
    AcceptHeaderLocaleContextResolver localeContextResolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleContextResolver();
    localeContextResolver.setDefaultLocale(this.webProperties.getLocale());
    return localeContextResolver;
}
```

You can provide your own `LocaleContextResolver` implementation to get the locale from the query parameter by providing a custom bean definition:

```java
//@Component("localeContextResolver")
@Component(WebHttpHandlerBuilder.LOCALE_CONTEXT_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME)
public class RequestParamLocaleContextResolver implements LocaleContextResolver {
    @Override
    public LocaleContext resolveLocaleContext(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        List<String> lang = exchange.getRequest().getQueryParams().get("lang");
        Locale targetLocale = null;
        if (lang != null && !lang.isEmpty()) {
            targetLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag(lang.get(0));
        }
        if (targetLocale == null) {
            targetLocale = Locale.getDefault();
        }
        return new SimpleLocaleContext(targetLocale);
    }

    @Override
    public void setLocaleContext(ServerWebExchange exchange, LocaleContext localeContext) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "Cannot change lang query parameter - use a different locale context resolution strategy");
    }
}
```

Note that the framework consumes the `LocaleContextResolver` with a specific name `localeContextResolver` (`WebHttpHandlerBuilder.LOCALE_CONTEXT_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME`). You need to provide the bean with the given name. See [#24209](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24209).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with spring boot starter web flux, which is much more cleaner, is to define your own `HttpHandler` using `WebHttpHandlerBuilder` in which you can set your `LocaleContextResolver`.

Documentation (see 1.2.2. WebHandler API) : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-config-customize

**MyLocaleContextResolver.java**

```
public class MyLocaleContextResolver implements LocaleContextResolver {


    @Override
    public LocaleContext resolveLocaleContext(ServerWebExchange exchange) {      
        return new SimpleLocaleContext(Locale.FRENCH);        
    }

    @Override
    public void setLocaleContext(ServerWebExchange exchange, LocaleContext localeContext) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Then in a config file (annotated with `@Configuration`) or in your spring boot application file, defined your own `HttpHandler` bean.

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpHandler httpHandler(ApplicationContext context) {

        MyLocaleContextResolver localeContextResolver = new MyLocaleContextResolver();

        return WebHttpHandlerBuilder.applicationContext(context)
                .localeContextResolver(localeContextResolver) // set your own locale resolver
                .build();

    }

}
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jonatan Mendoza's answer, but simpliefied and in kotlin:

```
/**
 * Override Accept-Language header by "lang" query parameter.
 */
@Component
class LanguageQueryParameterWebFilter : WebFilter {
  override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
    val languageValue = exchange.request.queryParams.getFirst("lang") ?: ""
    if (languageValue.isEmpty()) {
      return chain.filter(exchange)
    }
    return chain.filter(
      exchange.mutate().request(
        exchange.request
          .mutate()
          .headers {
            it[HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] = languageValue
          }
          .build(),
      ).build(),
    )
  }
}
```