# How to configure request-context-attribute programmatically in Spring WebFlux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, freemarker, spring-webflux

According to the comment of [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10094), Spring WebFlux supports `spring.freemarker.request-context-attribute` and actually it works properly. But now, I have to provide my extension of `DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration`. According to the [official guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-view-freemarker) and the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47527504/how-to-configure-i18n-in-spring-boot-2-webflux-thymeleaf), I just extends the `DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration` class as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class MyDelegatingWebFluxConfiguration extends DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration {
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.freeMarker();
    }
}
```

Then, everything seems fine except the `request-context-attribute` for I got the exception of:

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> request  [in template "index.ftl" at line 8, column 20]

Tip: If the failing expression is known to legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??

FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
- Failed at: ${request.contextPath}  [in template "index.ftl" at line 8, column 18]
```

in which the reference of `request` is just the value of `spring.freemarker.request-context-attribute`.

Thus, could anyone help to handle the case please?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Spring Framework reference, you just need to have a configuration class that implements `WebFluxConfigurer` (you should not have `@EnableWebFlux` on it, [as it will disable Spring Boot auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-webflux-auto-configuration)).

Extending `DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration` is the same as `@EnableWebFlux` on a configuration class, it will tell Spring Boot that you wish to take full control over the WebFlux infrastructure setup.

You don't need to setup Freemarker yourself, Spring Boot will do that for you, and you can just configure things in your `application.properties`.

Using `WebFluxConfigurer` should solve the issue here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, but it seem it doesn't work at all. I add `spring.freemarker.request-context-attribute=request` in `application.properties` and try to use `${request.contextPath}` in my freemarker template file, it still says `freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:==> request`. Futher more, the reason that I use `DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration` rather than `WebFluxConfigurer` is locale-related configuration exists in `DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration` and I have to use it.